# Powershell table variables within foreach

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to put a table together or export this as a CSV. I'm looking for certain files in multiple directories and reporting the number of files per directory.

What I'm looking for:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Clients Test Folder\

Name, Count
ClientA 3
ClientB 4
ClientC 5
```

What I have so far gets me what I need, but doesn't format in a table form, and I haven't had luck putting it in my script.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Clients Test Folder" | Select Name | Export-Csv c:\users\Admin\documents\Client.csv
$client = Import-Csv c:\users\Admin\documents\Client.csv

foreach ($Name in $client)
{
    $path = Join-Path "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Clients Test Folder\" -ChildPath $Name.Name
    $count = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -File -Include *.txt, *.rtf, *.doc*, *.xls* | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $Name.Name
        Count = $count 
    }
}
```

My results:

```
Name             Count
----             -----
ClientA              3
ClientB              4
ClientC              5
```

Comment: What you show as 'What I'm looking for:' is not a table either, since it is a single line showing a path, followed by a table. Do you really just want a CSV file with Name/Count info? Do you want just the base folder name, or the full path for that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding your custom object to an array?

```
$output = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
```

Inside your loop

`$output.add([pscustomobject]@{
  Name = $Name.Name
  Count = $count 
})`

then you should be able to export your variable to a csv.